# Why do I need to add a dependency on material when I use material3 when I want to use e.g. BottomNavigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand the difference between these two dependencies and why I need them to create e.g. a `BottomNavigationItem` in M3.

So these are my dependencies:

```
def composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01")
implementation composeBom
androidTestImplementation composeBom
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata'
```

Now why do I need a dependency on both `androidx.compose.material3:material3` and `androidx.compose.material:material` to use `BottomNavigationItem` and just a regular M3 `Text`? Isn't this dependency `androidx.compose.material:material` just M1? Why isn't `BottomNavigationItem` available in M3?

Because I need to have dependencies on both, I always need to specify which library I want to use when I want to create a UI component, like `IconButton`:

[image]

I already made many mistakes by importing the UI components from both the M3 library and the other one, causing a strange UI because the components are rendered differently.

Why isn't `BottomNavigationItem` in M3, but many components are? Like `Scaffold`, `Text`, `Button`, etc.

Comment: I think you should use ```NavigationBarItem``` instead of ```BottomNavigationItem``` to be able to access M3 version of this component. as per documentation says: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#NavigationBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Material 3 you have a `NavigationBar` and a `NavigationBarItem` instead of a `BottomNavigationBar`.
To use a `NavigationBar` at the bottom of the screen you use a `Scaffold` and pass the `NavigationBar` in the `bottomBar` parameter:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = { NavigationBar {
        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = ...
            label = ...
            onClick = ...
            selected = ...
        )
        ...
    },
    content = ... 
}
```